# How to search for certain strings within an xml response

Tags: python, xml, amazon-s3

I am using urllib2 library to get access to an s3 bucket i have. I get an xml structure back. The problem is i want to find nodes in that structure that their Key starts with "part-"

i want to then extract and save those in a list/array whatever and loop through them afterwards to read the contents of those files

part of xml response

```
<Contents>
<Key>output/part-00000</Key>
<LastModified>2016-05-11T17:01:19.000Z</LastModified>
<ETag>"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"</ETag>
<Size>0</Size>
<StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
</Contents>
<Contents>
<Key>output/part-00001</Key>
<LastModified>2016-05-11T17:01:15.000Z</LastModified>
<ETag>"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"</ETag>
<Size>0</Size>
<StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
</Contents>
```

Right now i am doing the following

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

f = urllib2.urlopen("https://s3.amazonaws.com/*******")

tree = ET.parse(f)
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    print child
```

output

```
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Name' at 0x103a325d0>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Prefix' at 0x103a32610>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Marker' at 0x103a32690>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}MaxKeys' at 0x103a32710>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}IsTruncated' at 0x103a32750>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a32790>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a32950>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a32b10>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a32cd0>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a32e90>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a3e090>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a3e250>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a3e410>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a3e5d0>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a3e790>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a3e950>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a3eb10>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a3ecd0>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a3ee90>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a47090>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a47250>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a47410>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a475d0>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a47790>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a47950>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a47b10>
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents' at 0x103a47cd0>
```

i have tried various solutions using minidom, and xml.etree.ElementTree but i do not quite get it right.

So what i want is to loop through those xml nodes find all references of part-***** and save them in an array.

any help/clues is/are welcomed

Comment: Post the code you tried and what went wrong and we will fix it.

Comment: @AlexHall hey there, you can check what i tried above along with console output thanks

Comment: That's a start, you got all the nodes. "The problem is i want to find nodes in that structure that their Key starts with "part-"" Where have you tried to filter out those nodes?

Comment: i tried `for child in root.iter('Contents'):` but it returns back nothing which stops me from search those contents.

Comment: Let's make a [mcve]. Remove anything about S3 and urllib2 from the question because this is an XML parsing issue. Put some sample XML in a string literal directly in the code and use `fromstring`.

Comment: nvm i found what i was looking for cheers!

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
f = urllib2.urlopen("https://s3.amazonaws.com/******")

tree = ET.parse(f)
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root.findall('{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents'):
    for key in child.findall("{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Key"):
        print key.text
```